# error al compilar fichero main c++

Tags: c++, compilador, compilar, bucle-for, makefile

Hay un error que me ha salido varias veces, he modificado las clases para quitar ese error, pero me sigue saliendo al ejecutar el main , no sé a qué se refiere, se agradece ayuda.

este es el codigo del main:

```
#include<iostream>
#include "muro.hpp"

using namespace std;

int main(void){

    int altura=0;
    int anchotodoelmuro=0;
    cout<< "Introduzca el ancho total del muro que desea construir  "<<endl;
    cin>>anchotodoelmuro;
    cout<< "Introduzca la altura del muro que desea construir  "<<endl;
    cin>>altura;

    vectorfila r(anchotodoelmuro);
    muro d(altura,anchotodoelmuro);

}
```

esta es la declaracion de la clase muro:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include "vectorfila.hpp"
//Aquí creo los distintos muros posibles
using namespace std;


    class muro{
    private:
            //error comun:  error no matching function: cuando sale esto, mala declaracion de estructuras de datos
            int alto_;
            //hay dos estructuras de vectores aqui, un vector dentro de otro puse vectorbloque filastotales investigar
            //no necesito valoresfila, con filastotales[i].size() recorro una fila hasta la ultima posicion
            // vectoresbloques hace referencia a un muro
            vectoresbloques filamurooptimo;
            typedef vector<vectoresbloques> mposibles;
            mposibles murosoptimos;
            mposibles muroscompletos; //preguntar declarar en otra funcion
    public:
            muro(void);
            muro(int alto,int anchototal);
            ~muro();
    };
```

creo que el problema es con los constructores y como enlazar clase, según he encontrado en algunos posts antiguos aquí, pero no sé cómo corregirlo. Errores al compilar:

```
C:AppData\Local\Temp\ccssZ0oq.o main_muro.cpp:(.text+0x99): undefined reference to `vectorfila::vectorfila(int)'

C:AppData\Local\Temp\ccssZ0oq.o main_muro.cpp:(.text+0xae): undefined reference to `muro::muro(int, int)'

C:\AppData\Local\Temp\ccssZ0oq.o    main_muro.cpp:(.text+0x99): undefined reference to `vectorfila::vectorfila(int)'
C:\AppData\Local\Temp\ccssZ0oq.o    main_muro.cpp:(.text+0xae): undefined reference to `muro::muro(int, int)'
C:\AppData\Local\Temp\ccssZ0oq.o    main_muro.cpp:(.text+0xba): undefined reference to `muro::~muro()'
C:\AppData\Local\Temp\ccssZ0oq.o    main_muro.cpp:(.text+0xc6): undefined reference to `vectorfila::~vectorfila()'
C:ALIEN\AppData\Local\Temp\ccssZ0oq.o   main_muro.cpp:(.text+0xdc): undefined reference to `vectorfila::~vectorfila()'
F:  [Error] ld returned 1 exit status
```

Se agradece ayuda. Gracias

Comment: g++ main_muro.cpp -o main_muro @Trauma asi lo estoy compilando

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Veo que no has declarado la clase `vectorfila r(anchotodoelmuro);` solo la clase `muro` ademas en la clase `muro`, veo que declaras un vetor del tipo `vectoresbloques` pero no veo donde has definido dicha clase, `typedef vector<vectoresbloques> mposibles;`.